# changing file names of larger subset in bash (mac Terminal)

Tags: bash, terminal

I've got a load of .tif files labelled in the following way:

xxxx_01.tif; xxxx_02.tif; .... xxxx_95.tif

How can I change the name of the files in batches (i.e. files 01-16 change to condition_1; files 17-20 change to condition_2) whilst incrementing the labelling?

I've been doing the following command for renaming them all but I'm not sure how to just select a certain range:

```
a=1; 
for i in *.tif; 
do new=$(printf "%02d.tif" "$a"); 
mv -- "$i" "filename_$new"; 
let a=a+1; 
done
```

Cheers

Comment: Have a look at the rename command. It has a powerful syntax that may do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the filenames you are interested in, instead of globbing all the files in the folder:

```
for n in $(seq -w 1 16)
do
    original_tif="xxxx_${n}.tif"
    new_tif="condition_1_${n}.tif"
    mv "${original_tif}" "${new_tif}"
done
```